# Responsive tiles grid with static tile width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I´m trying to do responsive tiles grid with static tile width.

I don´t speak English well, so I tried to draw my problem.

[Image is here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/Blueprint.png)

I need have tiles grid in the middle, but don´t centring single tile.

I hope you understand what I need, and thank you for any reply.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, show it. If not, try something on your own before you ask a question. For now, we don't know what exactly is the problem for you.

Comment: Of course, trying to have some time. Just do not have any code, I'll try to find some.

Comment: Hi I tried to do but do not know how to do that tiles were always in the middle of the container. http://jsfiddle.net/xcw1grdc/

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxy49moL/1/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box{
    margin:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thansk for answer. But I need same spacing between tiles.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6597309/no.PNG

Comment: Use padding or margin for that